Laravel Herd doesn't work at all after reinstall
Both Valet and Herd stopped working. No sites would load, just 502 nginx errors.
I tried reinstalling both Herd and Valet, but that did not fix it. So I removed all traces of every version of PHP, nginx, dnsmasq, Valet, and Herd from my system.
Then I installed the latest version of Herd again after a restart and skipped installing Valet or using brew to install PHP or nginx in case of conflicts with Herd. No errors during setup.
Herd shows all services are running without any errors in the logs.
I re-added my sites folder where all my test domains were and Herd now shows the full list of sites as expected in the Sites menu option.
However, all .test domains just produce the error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in latest Chrome browser.

Try this one: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/herd-502-bad-gateway

The suggestion to make the sites secure in Herd oddly fixed the DNS issue for me as well.

For me, the bug appear after a Windows update, I try many solutions but didn't help. Reinstalling Herd solved my problem.
